# No signature of method: logback.appender()

Tags: groovy, logback, logback-groovy

I have a problem running a project with logback defined through logback.groovy file. No such problem appears when running logback.xml configuration

Here's an example of logback.xml config:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="testflow" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender" file="dbGripTest.log">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS,UTC} %5p - %m [%ex] [%c{0}:%L] [%t]%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="consoleMain" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS,UTC} %5p - %m [%ex] [%c{0}:%L] [%t]%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="consoleSolace" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS,UTC} %5p - %m [%c{0}]%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <root level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.db.testing" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleMain" />
        <appender-ref ref="testflow" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.db.taps" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleSolace" />
        <appender-ref ref="testflow" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

Here are contents of logback.groovy file:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.ERROR

appender("testflow", FileAppender) {
    file = "dbGripTest.log"
    append = false
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS,UTC} %5p - %m [%ex] [%c{0}:%L] [%t]%n"
    }
}

appender("consoleMain", ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS,UTC} %5p - %m [%ex] [%c{0}:%L] [%t]%n"
    }
}
appender("consoleSolace", ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS,UTC} %5p - %m [%c{0}]%n"
    }
}


root(ERROR)

logger("com.db.testing", DEBUG, ["testflow","consoleMain"])
logger("com.db.taps",DEBUG, ["testflow","consoleSolace"])
```

And that's what I get when running an app with groovy config:

```
Jun 10 07:37:33.312  INFO - Transport Receiver is listening on: [, idgrip/ccr/ext/abfx/request/uk] [SolaceTransport]
Jun 10 07:37:33.948 DEBUG - SNAP objects have been created [] [SNAPAdapter:-1] [main]
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: logback.appender() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, logback$_run_closure1) values: [testflow, class ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender, logback$_run_closure1@1a45193b]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:179)
    at logback.run(logback.groovy:9)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.runIfScript(GroovyBackend.java:95)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.loadGlue(GroovyBackend.java:77)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:69)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:65)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

What is really strange is that output is actually formatted as stated in config file - i.e., 1st string uses "consoleSolace" pattern and second string uses "consoleMain" pattern, so the file is somehow used and interpreted.

Version used(from dependency-tree plugin):

```
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.28.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.28.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.3:compile
```

Any ideas what causes this behavior? That's exactly how appender should be declared in logback.groovy, according to http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html

Answer (score 0):

As I was fixing another issue, caused by Cucumber, I've decided to check if it helps here. And it does.

That is because this .groovy file was Glued in Cucumber launch config and Cucumber seems to try to execute all .groovy files encountered. After I've changed Glue in launcher to only point to feature files, this error dissapered